# C++ use std::set with objects properly

Tags: c++, find, set, std

I am trying to store `Nodes` in `std::set` so that when I use the `set::find` method it is going to tell me that a `Node` is in the set if their states are the same. Do I need to somehow compare the other `Node` attributes in `operator==` and `compare`?

Can you help me?

Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <set>
    using namespace std;

    class Node {
        bool operator==(const Node& rhs) const {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if(this->state[i][j] != rhs.get_block(i,j)) {
                       return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
         }

         //other methods including constructor

         private:
             int zero_pos[2];//the coordinates of the 0 in the matrix
             int state[3][3];//the matrix with numbers
             int current_path;//the distance from root
             Node* predecessor;//the parent of the Node
     };

    struct compare {
      bool operator()(const Node& f , const Node& s) const{
        vector<int> _f , _s;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        _f.push_back(f.state[i][j]);
                        _s.push_back(s.state[i][j]);
                    }
                }
        return _f < _s;
      }
    };

    //then I use it like this:
    void main() {
        set<Node , compare> closed;
        Node *node = new Node();
        if(closed.find(*node) != closed.end()) {
            cout<<"Found it!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the state's of nodes change after they are added to the set? A set expects its elements to remain stable so that they always compare the same way.

Comment: @ScottLangham No, they are always the same.

Comment: Are you aware that it is not possible to store two elements (nodes in your case) that compare identically (have the same state) in a set.

Comment: Note that you don't need `==` for the set; it only uses the comparator.

Comment: Note that if you change `int state[3][3];` to `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>;`, you may directly use `return _f.state < _s.state;` in `compare`

Comment: @ScottLangham I am going to try not to store more than one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you only need to be able to compare the state.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you to decide how much of the object should act as a "key" for the set, and write your comparator accordingly. If you only want the set to look at the `state` matrix, and regard two nodes as equivalent if that matches, then your comparator is fine.

Note that you only need the `compare` functor for use with the set. It doesn't compare objects with `operator==` so you only need that if you have some other use for it.